# Are there certain types of trees mentioned in Jeremiah 17:8?

Tags: jeremiah

> (NIV) **Jer 17:7-8**  “But blessed is the one who trusts in the Lord, whose
>   confidence is in him.
>       (8) They will be like a **tree** planted by the water that sends out its roots by the stream. It does not fear when heat comes; its leaves are
>   always green. It has no worries in a year of drought and never fails
>   to bear fruit.”

Are there certain types of trees mentioned in this verse?

Comment: Do you mean does it mention a specific species? If so, why wouldn't it be translated?

Comment: What needs to be translated? I want to know more clearly, does it refer to certain types of trees at that time? Estimate in 600-700 BC

Comment: If that was the case, what possible reasons can you think of that the translators wouldn't include that information, instead erasing it into the generic "trees"? I can't think of any!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hebrew word underlying the highlighted word in the question is כְּעֵ֣ץ, *ka-es*, ([Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/keetz_6086.htm)) which is a preposition (translated 'like a') fused with the word עֵ֛ץ *es* which is the generic word in Hebrew for a tree, being unspecific botanically.

The same word,  עֵ֛ץ *es*, appears in Genesis 2:9 ([Biblehub](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/2-9.htm)) regarding *both* the tree of life *and* the tree of knowledge of good and evil.

Both of these concepts recur in scripture, but particularly the concept of a tree of life and this concept is seen also in the book of Revelation.

Jeremiah's words are reminiscent of the words of the first, untitled, Psalm which begins the book of Psalms :

> And he shall be like a tree planted by the rivers of water, that bringeth forth his fruit in his season; his leaf also shall not wither; and whatsoever he doeth shall prosper. [Psalm 1:3, KJV.]

This spiritual concept requires interpretation and requires the examination of a variety of scriptures in the law, the prophets and in the New Testament.

I would say, myself, that there is a definite allusion to the tree of life in Jeremiah's words in this passage and, as is often the case, John alludes, in turn, to Jeremiah's prophetic analogy when he clothes the apocalyptic visions, which he was granted to see, with words :

> And he shewed me a pure river of water of life, clear as crystal, proceeding out of the throne of God and of the Lamb.In the midst of the street of it, and on either side of the river, was there the tree of life, which bare twelve manner of fruits, and yielded her fruit every month: and the leaves of the tree were for the healing of the nations. [Revelation 22:1,2 KJV.]

Comment: Thank you for the reference

Comment: @MetrisSovian You're welcome.